# Why does a heating model work?

Tags: physics, exponential-function, mathematical-physics

I am referring to: $T=T_0 e^{kt}$ where T=temperature,t=time and k=constant. It seems to work, I as just curios to why it works?

Comment: It really does not work very well. Cooling/heating is a complicated phenomenon.

Comment: This is really a question of the physics behind the formula, though I think it appropriate here especially if the answer is cached in mathematical terms; so I added the physics and mathematical physics tags; hope that's OK.  (You can always change it back if you disagree.)  Cheers!

Comment: Many of the uses of facts and equations used with $e$ rely on definition of e where $e=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ like in growth and compound interest formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have shown below the derivation of this model from Newton's law of heating and cooling.

If the temperature difference,  ΔT, between the two bodies or between an object and the ambient is not too large, the rate of change of this temperature difference is nearly proportional to that temperature difference:

$\frac{dΔT}{dt} = - K ΔT$

$\frac{dΔT}{ΔT} = - Kdt$

$\ln(ΔT) = - Kt$

$(ΔT) = Ce^{-Kt}$

If at some time t = 0 the **temperature difference** is $ΔTo$,

$ΔT_{o} = Ce^{0}$

$ C = ΔT_{o}$

Thus the heating model is $(ΔT) = ΔT_{o}e^{-Kt}$

In all heat transfer modes, such as conduction, convection (except radiation) it has always been the temperature difference that governs heat transfer between tow bodies or states.

Therefore, when two bodies exchange energy thermally, the temperature of each will exponentially approach their common final equilibrium temperature.

Remark, I have taken the model to depict cooling by haveing the constant negative -K, if it were to be heating, the it is +K